# How to pass several shell variables to awk in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have written a shell script to get any column. 
The script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '{print $c}' c=${1:-1}
```

So that i can call it as

```
ls -l | column 2
```

But how do i implement it for multiple columns?
Say, it i want something like :

```
ls -l | column 2 3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, I wouldn't use awk at all:

```
columns() { tr -s '[:blank:]' ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f "$@"; }
```

This uses `tr` to squeeze all sequences of whitespace to a single space, then `cut` to extract the fields you're interested in.

```
ls -l | columns 1,5,9-
```

Note, you [shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: +1 for the right solution. I'd probably use `tr -s '[:blank:]' '\t'` just so you don't need to specify `-d ' '` in the cut args but nbd.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -v c="3,5" '
    BEGIN{ split(c,a,/[^[:digit:]]+/) }
    { for(i=1;i in a;i++) printf "%s%s", (i==1?"":OFS), $(a[i]); print "" }
'
```

Use any non-digit(s) you like as the column number separator (e.g. comma or space).

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -l | nawk -v r="3,5" 'BEGIN{split(r,a,",")}{for(i in a)printf $a[i]" ";print "\n"}'
```

Now you can simply change your `r` variable in shell script and pass it on.
or you can configure it in your shell script and use `r=$your_list_var`

What ever fields numbers are present in `$your_list_var` will be printed by awk command.
The example above print 3rd and 5th fields of `ls -l` output.

Comment: +1, but put the `split` in the `BEGIN` block so you don't have to do it for every line.

Comment: Will fail cryptically when the input file contains printf formatting characters and won't necessarily output fields in the input order, nor in the order of the argument. It will also add a space to the end of each line and a spurious newline between each output line.